# Mostrar el valor $_SESSION con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy pintando en HTML una `$_SESSION['variable']` de PHP y necesito manejarla con JavaScript.

**html.php**

```
<p id="elem" value=" <?php echo $_SESSION['variable']; ?> "></p>
```

El resultado de esta operación es:

```
<p id="elem" value="0"></p>
```

Por el momento, es el resultado esperado.

El problema es que al querer manejar el nuevo `value="0"` con JavaScript, me devuelve un error `undefined`.

**javascript.js**

```
console.log(elem.value);
>> undefined
```

Comment: `span` no tiene el atributo `value`, ¿has probado a usar un `<input type="hidden"/>` en su lugar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu intención es llamar a ese atributo, hazlo:
elem.getAttribute("value");

Pero debajo de cuando creas el control, si lo haces antes que el control se renderice seguira dando **undefined**

EDIT: Mantengo mi respuesta, para cualquiera de los dos casos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @jose

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, recuerda que PHP se ejecuta *En servidor* y Javascript *En cliente*. Tomando esto en cuenta y el proceso natural de un 'renderizado de las páginas' podemos ver que (de una manera muy muy somera) PHP -> HTML -> Javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por tanto, cada vez que preparas tu `<?php echo $_SESSION['variable'];`, este *ya* llega al preparado y listo navegador, por tanto así ya puedes ejecutar tu código Javascript.

Siguiendo tu ejemplo, tengo `<p id="elem" value="0"></p>`, así, para capturar ese valor uso (usando Jquery)

```
$(function () {    
    var valueQueNecesito = $('#elem').val();
    console.log(valueQueNecesito);   
});
```

Javascript (bastante básico)

```
var value = document.getElementById(elem).value;
```

saludos